# Stimulating Treasure Hunt?

Tags: word, cryptic-clues, sequence

The puzzle is broken into four parts, and each part yields a single letter.  Put them all together, and it'll spell out the thing that gets me up in the morning :-)

**PART 1**

1)  One who may think about gallantry! (6) (Solved: indubitablee)

2)  Vader, for instance, holds murderous forger (5) -(Solved: Silenus)

3)  It's poisonous, so mother gets a medical book first (5) - (Solved: Silenus)

4)  Draw on alien food store (6) - (Solved: Silenus)

5)  The panel broke up right wing design (8) - (Solved: M Oehm)

6)  Broken laces wrapped round thumb for defensive move (6) - (Solved M Oehm)

**PART 2**

((CEMNOPS + DEITTU) / ACINRSST) / DEEEPZ - DDEIKNR = ?

**PART 3** - (Solved: Beastly Gerbil & M Oehm)

General knowledge:

1) "The lady ____ protest too much". (4) - (Solved: Beastly Gerbil)

2) The venom of a puffer fish (12) - (Solved: Beastly Gerbil)

3) A film by Spike Lee. (2, 3, 5, 5) - (Solved: Beastly Gerbil)

4) One who sells needles and thread (in Britain) and men's clothes (in America). (11) - (Solved: Beastly Gerbil)

5) The movie 'Cabaret' was adapted from the novel 'Berlin Tales' by which British author? (11, 9) - (Solved: Beastly Gerbil)

**PART 4**

This sequence is missing its first item.  What is it?

?
cvcv
cvccv
cvccv
vccvcvc
cvcv
vcv

Hint for part 2:

> The words are partial anagrams.  Each word is missing...something, and the 'somethings' are all very similar in one important respect.  I admit, I may have made this bit too difficult.  It's my first puzzle.  If this hint isn't enough, I'll post another one tomorrow.

Hint for part 4:

> The c and v stand for two common words.  If you know these, you should be able to deduce the sequence.

Comment: The answers ALARM surely. At least that what gets me up :P

Comment: Rubio would probably say COKE but that may be taken the wrong way ;)

Comment: Your idea to keep track of which clue was solved and by whom is laudable, but such attributions are usually done in the answer, not the question. This places the burden on the answerers or editors of community wikis and takes it away from you. Nice puzzle, by the way.

Comment: I don't get it. Coffee has six letters :(

Comment: "Wife" has four letters!

Answer (score 5):

The final answer is

> JAVA

Although Part 2 remains unsolved.

---

Part 1 (thanks to Silenus and MOehm for helping here):

1) One who may think about gallantry! (6)

> KNIGHT - KNI(G)HT

2) Vader, for instance, holds murderous forger (5)

> SMITH - S(M)ITH

3) It's poisonous, so mother gets a medical book first (5)

> MAMBA - MA(MB)+A

4) Draw on alien food store (6)

> MARKET - MARK+ET

5) The panel broke up right wing design (8)

> ELEPHANT - The Panel *

6) Broken laces wrapped round thumb for defensive move (6)

> CASTLE - LAC(T)ES*

Next

> These answers can be added to WHITE or BLACK

which gives

> WB
> BB
> WW

(I think)

Giving the braille letter

> **J**

---

Part 2:

A1Z26 gives the sum:

> ((351314151619 + 459202021) / 1391418191920) / 45551626 - 4459111418

The first four sets of numbers gives a number incredibly small, something around

> $5.55^-9$ = $0.00000000555$

So the answer is basically

> -4459111418

So not sure if this is right, or what we are looking for here

---

Part 3:

1) "The lady ____ protest too much". (4)

> Hamlet quote: "The lady **doth** protest too much methinks"

2) The venom of a puffer fish (12)

> **Tetrodotoxin**

3) A film by Spike Lee. (2, 3, 5, 5)

> **[Do the right thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_the_Right_Thing)**

4) One who sells needles and thread (in Britain) and men's clothes (in America). (11)

> **Haberdasher** (https://english.stackexchange.com/a/69016/166903)

5) The movie 'Cabaret' was adapted from the novel 'Berlin Tales' by which British author? (11, 9)

> **[Christopher Isherwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Isherwood)**

@MOehm spotted that these answers contain the words 'dot', 'dash' and 'stop' indicating Morse Code. This gives the sequence

> ..-. stop

Which is Morse code for

> **V**

---

Part 4:

@Talal_Sharaa had the idea that 'c' could stand for consonant, and 'v' could stand for vowel.

<strike>This means that we are looking for one consonant or one vowel to replace a single ?. This can only be a vowel - A or I, and A fits the answer. I don't know what the sequence is though</strike>

See ffao's answer for the sequence

The answer is

> 'Alpha'

giving

> **A**

Comment: part 1.1, knight?

Comment: @indubitablee that answer had crossed my mind, but thats not really a cryptic clue. I'll ask the OP whether these supposed cryptics are actually cryptics

Comment: Beastly Gerbil:  

>!** For part 2, the answer is a whole number, and you don't have to use cryptography.  You've got all the general knowledge questions correct.  There's a link between the answers.

indubitablee:  Knight is correct for part 1

Comment: The answers to part 3 contain dot, dot, dot, dash, stop, so it's perhaps a V?

Comment: @MOehm oooh clever. Good spot

Comment: **1.2** S(M)ITH; [def] forger; **1.3**  MAM(B)A; [def] It's poisonous

Comment: @Silenus aah so these *are* cryptics. I haven't looked at them yet because I thought them invalid. Proved me wrong there then, thanks for the help! :)

Comment: **1.4** MARK+ET; [def] food store

Comment: ELEPHANT (the panel)* and CASTLE?

Comment: @Silenus pretty sure 1.3 is MA(MB)+A because medical book first = MB

Comment: Anyway, all the answers can be combined with either WHITE or BLACK and should yield a Braille letter, possibly a P?

Comment: M Oehm - So very, very close!  Not a P, though.

Silenus:  You're absolutely right.  I should have put firsts.

Comment: white, black, black, black, white, white might clue the braille letter J, suggesting JAVA as final answer with a pun on *stimulating* in the title.

Comment: @Silenus yeah had that but internet just blanked out :/ wouldn't get the pun, don't code but thanks for telling me

Comment: I have no solution for part 2, but the words have the letters in alphabetical order. There are anagrams of DUETTI, SANSCRIT [sic] andv KINDRED, but that doesn't get us very far, does it?

Comment: @MOehm good spot. I still have no idea on how we are supposed to get a sum and the letter A but...

Comment: Hint for part 2 (rot-13'd to prevent spoilerage):

**Gurfr ner cnegvny nantenzf.  V zhfg pbasrff, guvf orvat zl svefg chmmyr V znl unir zvfwhqtrq gur qvssvphygl yriry bs gurfr :-(**


Hint for part 4:  


**Jung zvtug p naq i fgnaq sbe?**

Comment: @Nellington: It is notoriously hard to judge the difficulty of puzzles. Even experienced posters get this wrong sometimes. I thought the difficulty for the two solved parts was just right. Your hints are buried in a long series of comments and are hard to find. It might be a good idea to edit the hints into the question. (You can use the spoiler markup with  `>!` instead of rot13.) This will also bump the question to the top of the front page, so that your puzzle might get more attention.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and I'm glad you liked parts 2 and 4.

Comment: can't the cv means: consent-vowel? then the first element of the sequence will be V because there are only few words that consist of only one letter and they are A, I sometimes O All are vowels. And we need the letter A to fit the Word JAVA

Comment: @Talal_Sharaa oooh that's really promising! (I assume you meant consonant vowel) I'll have a look at that

Comment: @Nellington for part 4 I believe we figured out what they stand for, no idea on the pattern though! There really should be some sort of indication on the pattern really

Comment: The same goes for part 2, which I think is too broad even with the hint. I think that the missing things indicate numbers somehow. But DEITTU, for example, plus TWO gives OUTWITTED. Plus AT (Shift + 2) it gives ATTITUDE and plus AL (atomic number 13) it gives ALTITUDE.

Comment: @MOehm I'm wondering maybe if we add different numbers? But yeah I agree its too broad. Too many possibilities

Comment: ACINRSST can be changed to narcissist if we add "is" and anagram the word, maybe all the produced words should relate to personality or behavior, but not sure,  as we have many options..

Answer (score 5):

Possible answer for part 4:

> If "c" means consonant and "v" means vowel, then the sequence could potentially be:
>
> ```
> ????? cvcv cvccv cvccv vccvcvc cvcv vcv ...
> alpha beta gamma delta epsilon zeta eta ...
> ```
>
> Making the missing element of the sequence vcccv.

Comment: Ha, very good! I had tried the NATO alphabet, but that doesn't have any three-letter words.

Comment: Aah nice. To broad but that likes this find all the better :P